# Creating an animation of stars moving down the screen on a website, dynamically updating their speed via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Today, I thought I'd implement a simple new visual into the little web-based space game I've been working on. I'd already implemented some nice looking twinkly stars in the background behind the ship, but I decided I wanted those stars to move downwards to make the ship seem like it was moving through space. The faster the ship was going, the faster the stars would move, and vice versa. This, coupled with some slight deviations in the speed of each star, would add a sense of depth and 3D space.

Well, it's the end of the day, and after 6 hours of tinkering with it, I just can't get it to fully work. With a lot of recoding and GitHub Copilot help, I've managed to get the basics working: the stars spawn properly, they move down the screen properly, and they even change their speed based on the speed of the ship. Unfortunately, however, each time their speed updates, they jump. Even when the speed itself stays exactly the same, they jump. This creates quite the jarring effect each time the speed increases or decreases, rather than the nice speed-up effect I was going for.

```js
function startDivertGame() {
    updateAllMeters();
    regenerateShield();
    initializeCoreTemperature();
    setInterval(calculateEnemyDistance, 100);
    gameOver = false;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scale-factor', enginePower.toString());
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--shield-health', shieldHealth.toString());
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--shield-power', shieldPower.toString());

    starSpawnInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (starCounter < 150) {
            createStar(enginePower + 0.1);
            starCounter++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(starSpawnInterval);
        }
    }, 50);
}

function createStar(speed) {
    const star = document.createElement('div');
    star.className = 'stars';

    const xPos = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    const yPos = -10;

    star.style.left = `${xPos}px`;
    star.style.top = `${yPos}px`;

    const size = Math.random() + 1;

    star.style.width = size + 'px';
    star.style.height = size + 'px';

    const twinklingDelay = Math.random() * 2;

    const randomFactor = Math.random() * 2 + 0.5;
    const newDuration = Math.max(1, 10 / (speed * randomFactor + 1));

    star.style.animation = `moveDown ${newDuration}s 0s linear infinite, twinkle 2s ${twinklingDelay}s infinite alternate`;
    star.style.animationPlayState = 'running';

    star.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
        if (star.getBoundingClientRect().top > window.innerHeight) {
            star.remove();
            const index = stars.indexOf(star);
            if (index !== -1) {
                stars.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });

    document.body.appendChild(star);
    stars.push(star);
}

function updateStarSpeed(enginePower) {
    stars.forEach(star => {
        star.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
        const currentDuration = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(star).animationDuration);
        const currentTime = Date.now();
        const elapsedTime = (currentTime - (star.animationStartTime || currentTime)) % currentDuration;

        const progress = elapsedTime / currentDuration;

        const randomFactor = Math.random() * 2 + 0.5;
        const newDuration = Math.max(1, 10 / (enginePower * randomFactor + 1));

        const adjustedElapsedTime = progress * newDuration;

        const twinklingDelay = Math.random() * 2;

        star.style.animationDuration = `${newDuration}s, 2s`;
        star.style.animationDelay = `${adjustedElapsedTime}ms, ${twinklingDelay}s`;

        star.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
        star.animationStartTime = currentTime - adjustedElapsedTime;
    });
}
```

There's my code currently for spawning and updating the stars. updateStarSpeed is called anytime enginePower changes.

CSS:

```css
body::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #000; /* Set your desired background color */
    overflow: hidden;
}


@keyframes moveDown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100vh); /* Start from the top of the viewport */
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(100vh); /* Move down to the bottom of the viewport */
    }
}


.stars {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff; /* Set your desired star color */
    animation: moveDown 10s linear infinite, twinkle 4s infinite alternate; /* Adjust duration values as needed */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Add this line */
    animation-play-state: running;
}


@keyframes twinkle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

My GitHub page for it is https://github.com/lcbmann/lcbmann.github.io, go to divert.js and divertgame.html.

I cannot for the life of me fix this. Turns out that dynamically modifying the speed of an animation just doesn't really work. I attempted deleting stars and creating new stars of different speeds at the same position after each update, but this didn't work either.

I feel like there must be a simpler and easier way to make this effect happen, but I just cannot figure it out. It seems so simple. Make a bunch of stars, have them go down the screen at a speed determined by a variable. How hard is that?

Here's a (hopefully) runnable code-snippet to show my problem

```js
let starSpawnInterval;
const stars = []; // Store references to the created stars
let starCounter = 0; // Counter to track the number of stars created
let enginePower = 0;

// Function to increase engine power
function increaseEnginePower() {
    enginePower += 1; // You can adjust the increment value as needed
    updateStarSpeed(enginePower);
}

// Create a button element
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'Increase Engine Power';

// Add event listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', increaseEnginePower);

// Append the button to the body
document.body.appendChild(button);

function createStar(speed) {
    const star = document.createElement('div');
    star.className = 'stars';

    const xPos = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    const yPos = -10;

    star.style.left = `${xPos}px`;
    star.style.top = `${yPos}px`;

    const size = Math.random() + 1;

    star.style.width = size + 'px';
    star.style.height = size + 'px';

    const twinklingDelay = Math.random() * 2;

    const randomFactor = Math.random() * 2 + 0.5;
    const newDuration = Math.max(1, 10 / (speed * randomFactor + 1));

    star.style.animation = `moveDown ${newDuration}s 0s linear infinite, twinkle 2s ${twinklingDelay}s infinite alternate`;
    star.style.animationPlayState = 'running';

    star.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
        if (star.getBoundingClientRect().top > window.innerHeight) {
            star.remove();
            const index = stars.indexOf(star);
            if (index !== -1) {
                stars.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });

    document.body.appendChild(star);
    stars.push(star);
}
function updateStarSpeed(enginePower) {
    stars.forEach(star => {
        const currentDuration = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(star).animationDuration);
        const currentTime = Date.now();
        const elapsedTime = (currentTime - (star.animationStartTime || currentTime)) % currentDuration;

        const progress = elapsedTime / currentDuration;

        const randomFactor = Math.random() * 2 + 0.5;
        const newDuration = Math.max(1, 10 / (enginePower * randomFactor + 1));

        const adjustedElapsedTime = progress * newDuration;

        const twinklingDelay = Math.random() * 2;

        star.style.animationDuration = `${newDuration}s, 2s`;
        star.style.animationDelay = `${adjustedElapsedTime}ms, ${twinklingDelay}s`;

        star.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
        star.animationStartTime = currentTime - adjustedElapsedTime;
    });
}
starSpawnInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (starCounter < 150) {
            createStar(enginePower + 0.1);
            starCounter++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(starSpawnInterval);
        }
    }, 50);
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10%, 90% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

body::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #000; /* Set your desired background color */
    overflow: hidden;
}


@keyframes moveDown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100vh); /* Start from the top of the viewport */
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(100vh); /* Move down to the bottom of the viewport */
    }
}


.stars {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff; /* Set your desired star color */
    animation: moveDown 10s linear infinite, twinkle 4s infinite alternate; /* Adjust duration values as needed */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Add this line */
    animation-play-state: running;
}


@keyframes twinkle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: the "jumps" are likely due to the fact that you are pausing the animation.  does it not update properly if you just leave the animation running?

Comment: Could you make a simple snippet which we can run and which shows the problem perhaps for just one star? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Claies nope, still the same issue either way

Comment: @AHaworth you can find the visual on the github, https://lcbmann.github.io/divertgame

Comment: @AHaworth added the visual code-snippet!